# How to run animation only if someone opens a tab (not page onload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am putting together a page that has tabs. The tabs are made with HTML and CSS only.

On the second tab, I have a simple bar graph animation. I want the animation to play only if the person click to see this specific tab.

Currently, the animation plays when the page loads, so by the time someone gets to the second tab, the animation is done.

Here's a link to [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2wc1sg7/1/)

```js
$(function(){
  $(".html").animate({width: "90%"}, 1500);
  $(".css").animate({width: "80%"}, 1500);
  $(".liquid").animate({width: "40%"}, 1500);
  $(".javascript").animate({width: "30%"}, 1500);
});
```

```css
 html, body {
    height: 100% !important;
    background: #BECDBB;
  }
  body {
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1015px) {
    body {
      background: #BECDBB;
     font-size: 16px;
     letter-spacing: 0.01em;
     padding: 10%; 
    }
   }
  .grid {
    margin-top: 5%;
    background: 
  }

  button:focus,
  input:focus,
  textarea:focus,
  select:focus {
    outline: none;
  }

.tabs {
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; }
  .tabs [class^="tab"] label,
  .tabs [class*=" tab"] label {
    color: #efedef;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 2rem 0;
    text-align: center; }
  .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"],
  .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"] {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(239, 237, 239, 0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }
    .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:hover, .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:focus,
    .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:hover,
    .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:focus {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #fd264f; }
    .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:checked,
    .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:checked {
      border-bottom: 2px solid #fd264f; }
    .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:checked + div,
    .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:checked + div {
      opacity: 1; }
    .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"] + div,
    .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"] + div {
      display: block;
      opacity: 0;
      padding: 2rem 0;
      width: 90%;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }
  .tabs .tab-2 {
    width: 50%; }
    .tabs .tab-2 [type="radio"] + div {
      width: 200%;
      margin-left: 200%; }
    .tabs .tab-2 [type="radio"]:checked + div {
      margin-left: 0; }
    .tabs .tab-2:last-child [type="radio"] + div {
      margin-left: 100%; }
    .tabs .tab-2:last-child [type="radio"]:checked + div {
      margin-left: -100%; }
      
      
 .container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.skills {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.html {
width: 0;
background-color: #526279;
}
.css {width: 0; background: #959fad;}
.liquid {width: 0; background: #3d4654;}
.javascript {width: 0; background: #7a899e;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid">

  <div class="grid-item large--two-thirds push--large--one-sixth">
    <header>
      <h1 class="text-center">Title</h1>
      <hr class="hr--small">
    </header>
    <div class="rte">      
      
     
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab-2">
    <label for="tab2-1">One</label>
    <input id="tab2-1" name="tabs-two" type="radio" checked="checked">
    <div>
      <h4>Tab One</h4>
      
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas consequat id velit quis vestibulum. Nam id orci eu urna mollis porttitor. Nunc nisi ante, gravida at velit eu, aliquet sodales dui. Sed laoreet condimentum nisi a egestas.</p><p>Donec interdum ante ut enim consequat, quis varius nulla dapibus. Vivamus mollis fermentum augue a varius. Vestibulum in sapien at lectus gravida lobortis vulputate sed metus. Duis scelerisque justo et maximus efficitur. Donec eu eleifend quam. Curabitur aliquet commodo sapien eget vestibulum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vestibulum vel aliquet nunc, finibus posuere lorem. Suspendisse consectetur volutpat est ut ornare.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-2">
    <label for="tab2-2">Two</label>
    <input id="tab2-2" name="tabs-two" type="radio">
    <div>
      <p>HTML</p>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="skills html">90%</div>
      </div>

      <p>CSS</p>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="skills css">80%</div>
      </div>

      <p>JavaScript</p>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="skills liquid">40%</div>
      </div>

      <p>PHP</p>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="skills javascript">30%</div>
      </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
      
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `$(function(){})` runs at page load.  You just need to make it a function that you can call, and then add a click handler to the tab-2, like this:

`$('#tab2-2').click(animate);`

Where `animate` is the name of the function you created.  Here's a snippet.

```js
function animate() {
  $(".html").animate({width: "90%"}, 1500);
  $(".css").animate({width: "80%"}, 1500);
  $(".liquid").animate({width: "40%"}, 1500);
  $(".javascript").animate({width: "30%"}, 1500);
}

$('#tab2-2').click(animate);
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100% !important;
    background: #BECDBB;
  }
  body {
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1015px) {
    body {
      background: #BECDBB;
     font-size: 16px;
     letter-spacing: 0.01em;
     padding: 10%; 
    }
   }
  .grid {
    margin-top: 5%;
    background: 
  }

  button:focus,
  input:focus,
  textarea:focus,
  select:focus {
    outline: none;
  }

.tabs {
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; }
  .tabs [class^="tab"] label,
  .tabs [class*=" tab"] label {
    color: #efedef;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 2rem 0;
    text-align: center; }
  .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"],
  .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"] {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(239, 237, 239, 0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }
    .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:hover, .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:focus,
    .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:hover,
    .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:focus {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #fd264f; }
    .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:checked,
    .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:checked {
      border-bottom: 2px solid #fd264f; }
    .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:checked + div,
    .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:checked + div {
      opacity: 1; }
    .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"] + div,
    .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"] + div {
      display: block;
      opacity: 0;
      padding: 2rem 0;
      width: 90%;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }
  .tabs .tab-2 {
    width: 50%; }
    .tabs .tab-2 [type="radio"] + div {
      width: 200%;
      margin-left: 200%; }
    .tabs .tab-2 [type="radio"]:checked + div {
      margin-left: 0; }
    .tabs .tab-2:last-child [type="radio"] + div {
      margin-left: 100%; }
    .tabs .tab-2:last-child [type="radio"]:checked + div {
      margin-left: -100%; }
      
      
 .container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.skills {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.html {
width: 0;
background-color: #526279;
}
.css {width: 0; background: #959fad;}
.liquid {width: 0; background: #3d4654;}
.javascript {width: 0; background: #7a899e;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid">

  <div class="grid-item large--two-thirds push--large--one-sixth">
    <header>
      <h1 class="text-center">Title</h1>
      <hr class="hr--small">
    </header>
    <div class="rte">      
      
     
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab-2">
    <label for="tab2-1">One</label>
    <input id="tab2-1" name="tabs-two" type="radio" checked="checked">
    <div>
      <h4>Tab One</h4>
      
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas consequat id velit quis vestibulum. Nam id orci eu urna mollis porttitor. Nunc nisi ante, gravida at velit eu, aliquet sodales dui. Sed laoreet condimentum nisi a egestas.</p><p>Donec interdum ante ut enim consequat, quis varius nulla dapibus. Vivamus mollis fermentum augue a varius. Vestibulum in sapien at lectus gravida lobortis vulputate sed metus. Duis scelerisque justo et maximus efficitur. Donec eu eleifend quam. Curabitur aliquet commodo sapien eget vestibulum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vestibulum vel aliquet nunc, finibus posuere lorem. Suspendisse consectetur volutpat est ut ornare.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-2">
    <label for="tab2-2">Two</label>
    <input id="tab2-2" name="tabs-two" type="radio">
    <div>
      <p>HTML</p>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="skills html">90%</div>
      </div>

      <p>CSS</p>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="skills css">80%</div>
      </div>

      <p>JavaScript</p>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="skills liquid">40%</div>
      </div>

      <p>PHP</p>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="skills javascript">30%</div>
      </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
      
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! I was having trouble figuring that out. Now that i'm looking at it, it makes sense. Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome!   Don't forget to mark that as an accepted answer so other people don't get confused!